# Phonegap: ./create error

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new with Phonegap, and am using the Terminal to try and develop it with. I am trying to make it so the project is accessible in Xcode.

I'm stuck at creating the project. I type in:

> ./create ~/Desktop/ProjectFolderName com.myName.hello projectNameForXCodeRefferal

And I am getting the error:

> -bash: ./create: No such file or directory

I managed to zone to a bin from using:

> ~/.cordova

I have been stuck on this for days. I am finding similar errors online, but I have referred to documentation and other StackOverflow topics without success. Is someone willing to give a hand here?

EDIT:
My entire command is this:

> /Users/Evee/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/codova-ios/3.8.0/package/bin/create
>   ~/Desktop com.myName.myProj myProj

I get this error now:

> -bash: /Users/Evee/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/codova-ios/3.8.0/package/bin/create:
>   No such file or directory

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I am unsure of how I was able to resolve it, but I "SUDO" (aka, root/superuser/elevated admin) commanded to uninstall cordova, and manually entered cordova 2.8.0 as the installation. Following this resource on Github.

https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/create-cordova-project.html